# an overlay for describing application features on first time install

Tags: ios

I'm building an app, i just thinking like adding a feature so, that the user can be given guideline about how to use the app and various control in it.

The feature that came to my mind is , when unboxing android mobile you will see an overlay describing the menu, app .

so, is there any similar feature that iOS or any third party library provides. if so, will app store testing team will approve it.

see this image "http://developer.android.com/design/media/help_cling.png", for further reference.

Comment: You can build one / search for one. Multiple apps have a guided intro sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using these:

- [myblurintroductionview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/myblurintroductionview)
- [wscoachmarksview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wscoachmarksview)
- [rchgestureguide](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rchgestureguide)